# In a paket.dependencies file, what is the meaning of the operator `==`?

Tags: paket

In a project's paket.dependencies file, I found thoses lines:

```
nuget Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc == 5.2.6
nuget Microsoft.AspNet.Razor == 3.2.6
nuget Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages == 3.2.6
```

I checked the [official documentation](https://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/dependencies-file.html) without success. 
My guess would be that `==` could fix a version number but to achieve this we can directly write `nuget Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 5.2.6`.

What is the meaning of the operator `==`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called the "Use exactly this version" constraint. It really should be part of the paket.dependencies reference but instead it is found in: https://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/nuget-dependencies.html

I'll try to explain it with an example. Imagine that you depend on packages A & B.

Both A and B depend on C but in their respective nuget package dependency declaration they specify that:

A depend on C version >= 1.2.3 but < 2.0

B depend on C version >= 2.0

In this situation paket will fail to find a common version of C that suits both A and B.

I've seen cases in some projects where there is a dependency to a package like A that claims it won't work with versions >= 2.0 of package C. However when actually tested, A works just fine with the highest version of C. Therefore a line to force paket to override the version constraint A have on C can be added:

```
nuget C == 2.0
```

Of course, the long term solution is to ask the maintainer of A to update their nuget dependency declaration.

Answer (score 1):

Paket is an Open Source project. Lets dig the source. The paket.dependencies file parse is available on GitHub. Here is the logic:

```
match splitVersion text with
    | "==", version :: rest -> 
        let v = SemVer.Parse version
        VersionRequirement(VersionRange.OverrideAll v,parsePrerelease [v] rest)
    | ">=", version :: rest -> 
        let v = SemVer.Parse version
        VersionRequirement(VersionRange.Minimum v,parsePrerelease [v] rest)
    | ">", version :: rest -> 
        let v = SemVer.Parse version
        VersionRequirement(VersionRange.GreaterThan v,parsePrerelease [v] rest)
    | "<", version :: rest -> 
        let v = SemVer.Parse version
        VersionRequirement(VersionRange.LessThan v,parsePrerelease [v] rest)
    | "<=", version :: rest -> 
        let v = SemVer.Parse version
        VersionRequirement(VersionRange.Maximum v,parsePrerelease [v] rest)
    | "~>", minimum :: rest -> 
        let v1 = SemVer.Parse minimum
        VersionRequirement(VersionRange.Between(minimum,twiddle v1),parsePrerelease [v1] rest)
    | _, version :: rest -> 
        let v = SemVer.Parse version
        VersionRequirement(VersionRange.Specific v,parsePrerelease [v] rest)
| _ -> failwithf "could not parse version range \"%s\"" text
```

[source](https://github.com/fsprojects/Paket/blob/bfb5155ba623a51e22da1b31e50608bed0575e81/src/Paket.Core/Dependencies/DependenciesFileParser.fs#L101)

So `==` will set the VersionRange to `OverrideAll`. This will have an impact on `IsGlobalOverride`.

```
member x.IsGlobalOverride =
    match x with
   | OverrideAll _ -> true
   | _ -> false
```

[source](https://github.com/fsprojects/Paket/blob/9cbc7a05fc851611e541051d8f07beb8d25e9596/src/Paket.Core/Versioning/VersionRange.fs#L19)

To conclude `==` will override the package at the given version, when without, the current package at the given version will be used. This is a rough understanding, please and any thorough answer beside.